How to configure an HTTPS proxy (HTTPS connection to proxy)
Is it possible to set up an HTTPS proxy on Android to route all HTTP/HTTPS traffic over an HTTPS connection? I want to establish an SSL connection between my app and the proxy server.
(my app) <- https connection to proxy -> (proxy server) <-> (internet)

I’ve seen that Proxy in Android takes a SocketAddress to configure HTTP proxy. But I need to use an SSL connection here, so I could use https://my.proxy-server.com as a proxy address.
How can I achieve this? Similar questions in the end assume HTTP connection to the proxy, while I need HTTPS. Also, there are some suggestions to use Drony application for that, so this should be possible. But how to implement this in my application?

What exactly in your app needs to talk through the proxy server? For example, it if is a Web service call, OkHttp apparently supports proxy servers, so you could use that as your Web service client.
